# Use form button to submit GET value

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code to submit GET values:

```
<form method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="ASC" />
  <input type="submit" value="Price Low to High" />
</form>

<form method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="DESC" />
  <input type="submit" value="Price High to Low" />
</form>

<form method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Default" />
</form>
```

Which is working fine. So I am not repeating myself with three forms, is there a way I could have a single form, and define what GET values are submitted by the buttons? They would still need to have the same information visible to the user e.g. the button that submits `DESC` needs to display as `Price High to Low`

Comment: combine them all in one form and  put a `name` on your `submit buttns.`  like `<input type="submit" value="Default" name="action" />`

Comment: Why not a link instead of form? And for form you can javascript to switch values before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="submit"  name="price" value="ASC">Price Low to High</input>
  <input type="submit" name="price" value="DESC"  >Price High to Low</input>

 <input type="submit" name="price" value="" >Default</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If having three buttons is not obligatory by design, then I suggest, why not just use a `select` to let the user decide what he wants (as most of the sites already do)

```
<form method="GET">
 <select id="price" name="price">
   <option value="">Default</option>
   <option value="ASC">Price Low to High</option>
   <option value="DESC">Price High to Low</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Price Low to High" />
</form>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/jWzgpw)**

And if having three buttons is necessary then, you could do either one of (though not limited to) the following..

1. Use plain links (`<a>` anchor tags), yup you read that correct, since the form is just submitting using the `$_GET` method, eventually the data is gonna be inside the URLs, so why not just have it there in the first place using the `href` attributes of the "*buttons*" ?
2. Use the solution that @Aref Anafgeh suggested, and have three submit buttons each with different values and just let the html handle which value is sent to the server.
3. Use JavaScript and make ajax calls, which pretty much allows you to handle what is & isn't sent in the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get">

<select name="sort">
  <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
  <option value="desc">Descending</option>
  <option value="default">Default</option>
</select>

<button name="price">Sort price ascending</button>
</form>
```

*snip*

```
<?php if ($_GET['sort'] == "asc") {
// Do something
} elseif ($_GET['sort'] == "desc") {
// Do something else 
}
// etc
?>
```

Hyperlinks to http://url/?price=XXX would also work fine since you're using `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") 
    {
       echo "Form Submited by ".$_GET['submitbutton']." Button";
    } 
?>      
        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="ASC" />
            <input type="submit" value="Price Low to High" name="submitbutton"/>
        </form>

        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="DESC" />
            <input type="submit" value="Price High to Low" name="submitbutton"/>
        </form>

        <form method="GET" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Default" name="submitbutton"/>
        </form>

        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: action should not reference `PHP_SELF`, there is a significant potential for security holes in this approach, although the use of htmlspecialchars is noted. http://www.mc2design.com/blog/article/serverphp_self-can-not-be-trusted-but-there-are-safe-alternatives

Comment: i Could use # instead of, i could leave it empty.

Comment: `$_SERVER['script_filename']` will work. `#` does not submit the form and the action element is required to be filled. Many people use PHP_SELF as a minor shortcut but it has serious issues.